# Is there a dynamic inventory for VMware in Ansible?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, ansible

The documentation for [Dynamic Inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html) makes mention of so many dynamic inventories, but none for VMware.

I really liked the feature of tagging servers in Amazon EC2 and was hoping to re-create a similar system in our VMware environment.

Fetch all servers in vSphere with tags "environment=testing" and "application=helloworld" and run this Ansible playbook on them.

Answer (score 10):

> Is there a dynamic inventory for VMware in Ansible?

There are two in the official Ansible repository:

- [vmware.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/contrib/inventory/vmware.py) - an old one based on pysphere
- [vmware_inventory.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/contrib/inventory/vmware_inventory.py) - a new one based on pyvmomi

Refer to the code and the configuration files ([`vmware.ini`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/contrib/inventory/vmware.ini), [`vmware_inventory.ini`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/contrib/inventory/vmware_inventory.ini)) for usage details.

---

Alternatively you can fetch the VMs facts with [`vmware_vm_facts` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/vmware_vm_facts_module.html) and create your own in-memory inventory with [`add_host`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/add_host_module.html).

Comment: It is still unclear how to do what the question asked, namely, `Fetch all servers in vSphere with tags "environment=testing" and "application=helloworld"`